# Slide-out panel using Swift/OS X

Tags: swift, macos, nswindow, nsviewcontroller

Not sure there's a better way to describe this. It's almost like `presentViewControllerAsSheet(vc)` but presented non-modally, and not sliding out from the top of the window frame. I've searched and searched for solutions, but can't find anything that works. I think it's possible, since Apple's Mail 'Connection Doctor' window uses one for the Log Viewer, but I can't find any way to do it.

[image]

If anyone has any suggestions or pointers to tutorials on how to accomplish such a thing, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: I'm not sure about OSX but I know on iOS you can set the context to 'Current Context' which should present it in the view that you want. There is also 'Over Current Context'

Comment: This thing is called a [drawer](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Drawers/Concepts/DrawerSizing.html). I'm surprised that Apple still uses it in one of their apps since it's been some time they've discouraged everyone to use them... :p